# boost::lambda::bind - possible optimization?

Tags: c++, boost, lambda, bind

Check the following code:

Global wrapper function:

```
static Storage::Stream::Object reqStreamStatic( Storage::Stream::Object& stream, const std::string& identifier )
{
    return stream;
}
```

Declaration of a boost::function:

```
Storage::Stream::Object stream( file, iFormat );

BOOST_AUTO( onReqStream, boost::lambda::bind( &Impl::reqStreamStatic, boost::lambda::var( stream ), boost::lambda::_1 ) );
```

As you can see the wrapper function does only return the given stream. Now I am looking for a solution to remove the wrapper function so the resulting coded looks like this:

```
BOOST_AUTO( onReqStream, boost::lambda::ret< Storage::Stream::Object >( boost::lambda::bind( boost::lambda::var( stream ), boost::lambda::_1 ) ) );
```